# calling a function before redirecting to 404 page on findOrFail

Tags: php, laravel

when i delete something from database ... lets say a blog  ,  i might want to redirect the link for that blog to another link instead of 404 page

i have a table called `setting_redirects` :

```
setting_redirects : id , deleted_link , redirect_link
```

i'll store the deleted links and new link in this table

this is how i show a blog

```
function show( $blog_id ){

   $blog = Blog::findOrFail($blog_id);
}
```

the problem is if it's not found `findOrFail` will automatically redirect user to 404 page ... i want to be able to check`setting_redirects` to see if a redirect is available for that blog .... if so redirect to that new link otherwise go to 404

something like this

```
function show( $blog_id ){

   $blog = Blog::find($blog_id);
   if(!$blog)
   {
      $redirect_available = SettingRedirect::where('deleted_link ' ,  Request::url() ) ->first();
     if($redirect_available )
       return redirect( $redirect_available-> redirect_link );
      else 
       abort(404);
   }
}
```

but i want this for all my tables not only blogs and i dont want to write this code in all of my controllers

is there anyway to do this without changing all my controllers ? maybe a middleware before going to 404 page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findOrFail` throws a `ModelNotFoundException`. I think you can simply catch and rethrow it.

```php
try {
    $blog = Blog::findOrFail($blog_id);
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    $redirect_available = SettingRedirect::where('deleted_link', Request::url())->first();
    if ($redirect_available)
        return redirect($redirect_available->redirect_link);

    throw $e;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can put this logic in the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file inside the `register()` method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
            // this is to make sure the exception was caused by a findOrFail operation 
            if ($e->getPrevious() instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
                $redirect_available = SettingRedirect::where('deleted_link', $request->url())->first();

                if ($redirect_available) {
                    return redirect($redirect_available->redirect_link);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The reason why the first line is 
`$this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) { ... })` instead of
`$this->renderable(function (ModelNotFoundException $e, $request) { ... })`

is because Laravel does this weird thing of transforming `ModelNotFoundException` into `NotFoundHttpException` before it's available to the exception handler.

Comment: thanx , but still i have to put this in all of my controllers ... this  would be plan B

Comment: I'm editing the answer with plan A at the moment.

Comment: With this, you don't have to worry about putting that logic in the controller anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think need to change status of that particular record while deleting action, code on 404, if query executeble then include "mypage.php"; else would show default 404 page